# What does x = y mean in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

This question has been raised because of a certain example I encountered while reading about actual and formal arguments. Let x and y be 2 non-iterable variables

```
def fun(y):
    x=y
    x=3

y=5
fun(y)
print y 
#yields 5 and hence I have been led to believe that 2 separate copies of x and y exist wherein if a change is made to x ,nothing is reflected in y.
```

However if y were a list and a value were to be changed in the function,the changes would be reflected outside the function as well.

```
def func(a):
    x = a
    x[0]="abhi"

a = ["ari", "gold", "silver"]
func(a)
print a

 # yields ["abhi", "gold", "silver"]
```

Why the discrepancy in the definition of x=y when it comes to lists and normal variables ?

Comment: Read [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

Comment: What you say about lists simply isn't true.

Comment: @Daniel Please refer to the changes I have made in the question description and kindly tell why what i said isn't true.

Comment: Because in that code you're not doing the same thing at all. You're mutating an element of the list, not changing what the name refers to.

Comment: But that is exactly what I had originally intended to ask. When x=y and y is a list,if 2 copies of the list exist in x and y, a change in x shouldn't make a change in y. Which it does. Why is the same not applicable to normal non-iterable variables ?

Comment: @delnan, Thanks a lot. The mutable presto chango rule cleared my doubt.

Answer (score 4):

This line:

```
x=y
```

… is just an assignment that says: store the value of `y` in a new variable called `x`. It's a superfluous assignment, because in the next line you re-assigned the value of `x` to a new value.

Why do you think it should have changed the value of `y`? assignments store whatever value that's to the right of `=` in the variable to the left, so clearly we never modified `y` after the first assignment.

Answer (score 0):

You are reassigning `x` with new data.

`x=y` is not a formula to be maintained, it simply performs the action of replacing `x`'s value the same value of y

The only case I can think of what you're describing is in this example.

```
class test:
    a = "entity"

>>> t1 = test()
>>> t1.a
'entity'
>>> test.a = "no_name"
>>> t1.a
'no_name'
```

In this case, when you create `t1` from `test`,  `t1.a` is *"following"* the base class value, so when I change `test.a`'s value, `t1.a` will still point to `test.a` location.

This will however be prevented as soon as you assign `t1`'s `a` with a new value. This is because it will now be following its own data.

```
>>> t1.a = "yes name"
>>> test.a
'no_name'
>>> t1.a
'yes name'
>>>
```

Comment: "replacing `x`'s value with a copy of `y`... or a reference to what `y` is holding" - not true, it simply assigns `x` to the *same object* `y` is assigned to, irrespective of whether `y` is or isn't mutable.